# Implementation of an EM algorithm for POMDP

Tags: python, algorithm, hidden-markov-models

I implemented the algorithm described in the paper "Learning Partially Observable Markov Decision Model with EM Algorithm".

To test it I randomly generated a pomdp with 2 states, 2 actions and 2 observations. Then I simulated an episode and fed the algorithm with the lists of the actions and observations.

The calculated probabilities do not converge to the true probabilites although the likelihood of the observations rises. For long sequences (~800) I get a division by zero error while calculating xi.

I reviewed my code many times but I am not finding any problem. Are there any detailed experiments I can try my algorithm with?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np

#s        - number of actions
#n        - number of states
#r        - number of observations
#A[a,i,j] - probability of transition from state i to state j                            
#           given action a
#O[a,j,o] - probability of observing o when entering state j                              
#           given action a
#pi[j]    - probability that the initial state is j
#Act      - a list of actions
#Obs      - a list of observations, the j-th observation corresponds to the 
#           j-th action

class POMDP:
    def __init__(self, Obs, Act, A, O, pi):
        self.T = len(Obs)
        self.Obs = Obs
        self.Act = Act
        self.A = A
        self.O = O
        self.pi = pi
        self.s = self.A.shape[0]
        self.n = self.A.shape[1]
        self.r = self.O.shape[2]
        self.alpha = np.zeros((self.T+1,self.n))
        self.beta = np.zeros((self.T+1,self.n))
        self.chi = np.zeros((self.T+1,self.n))
        self.xi = np.zeros((self.T+1,self.n,self.n))

    def alpha_beta_calc(self):
        for j in range(self.n):
            self.alpha[0,j] = self.pi[j]
            self.beta[self.T,j]= 1.0            

        for t in range(1, self.T+1):
            for j in range(self.n):
                self.alpha[t,j] = sum([self.A[self.Act[t- 
                1],i,j]*self.alpha[t-1,i]*self.O[self.Act[t-1],j,self.Obs[t- 
                1]] for i in range(self.n)])
                self.beta[self.T-t,j] = sum([self.A[self.Act[self.T- 
                t],j,i]*self.O[self.Act[self.T-t],i,self.Obs[self.T- 
                t]]*self.beta[self.T- t+1,i] for i in range(self.n)])

    def xi_chi_calc(self):      
        for t in range(0, self.T+1):
            l = sum([self.alpha[t,k]*self.beta[t,k] for k in range(self.n)])

            for i in range(self.n):
                self.chi[t,i]=self.alpha[t,i]*self.beta[t,i]/l
                for j in range(self.n):
                    self.xi[t,i,j]=(self.alpha[t-1,i]*self.A[self.Act[t- 
                    1],i,j]*self.O[self.Act[t-1],j,self.Obs[t- 
                    1]]*self.beta[t,j])/l

    def pi_calc(self):
        for j in range(self.n):
            self.pi[j] = self.chi[0,j]

    def A_calc(self):        
        for i in range(self.n):
            for j in range(self.n):
                for a in range(self.s):
                    nom = sum([self.xi[t,i,j] for t in range(1,self.T+1) if 
self.Act[t-1] == a])
                    denom = sum([self.chi[t-1,i] for t in range(1,self.T+1) 
if self.Act[t-1] == a])
                    self.A[a,i,j] = nom/denom

    def O_calc(self):
        for j in range(self.n):
            for k in range(self.r):
                for a in range(self.s):
                    nom = sum([self.chi[t,j] for t in range(1, self.T+1) if 
(self.Act[t-1] == a) and (self.Obs[t-1] == k)])
                    denom = sum([self.chi[t,j] for t in range(1, self.T+1) 
if self.Act[t-1] == a])
                    self.O[a,j,k] = nom/denom
def sim(l, A, O, pi):
    obs=[]
    act=[]
    if np.random.rand()>pi[0]: curr = 1
    else: curr = 0
    states = [curr]
    for _ in range(l):
        a = np.random.randint(0,2)

        if np.random.rand()<A[a, curr, 1]: curr = 1
        else: curr = 0
        if np.random.rand()<O[a, curr, 1]: o = 1
        else: o =0
        obs.append(o)
        act.append(a)
        states.append(curr)
    return act,obs,states

def generate(length = 1000):
    A = np.random.rand(2,2,2)
    O = np.random.rand(2,2,2)
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            A[i,j,1]=1.0-A[i,j,0]
            O[i,j,1]=1.0-O[i,j,0]

    pi = np.random.rand(2)    
    pi[1]=1.0-pi[0]
    act,obs,states = sim(length, A, O, pi)
    return A, O, pi, act,obs,states

#generate random pomdp and a simulation of a given length
A, O, pi,act,obs,states = generate()

#initialize matrices randomly
A, O, pi,act1,obs1,states1 = generate()
pomdp = POMDP(obs, act, A, O, pi)

for _ in range(100):
    pomdp.alpha_beta_calc()        
    pomdp.xi_chi_calc()
    pomdp.A_calc()
    pomdp.O_calc()
    pomdp.pi_calc()
```